# sweetalert2 example reports: await is only valid in async functions and async generators

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sweetalert2

I use **[sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)** for some dialogs in my application. However, the the [sweetalert2 website](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) provides some examples that reported this error when I literally copy/pasted them in my webapplication code:

`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators`

After some research I added **`async`** before `function testSweetalert()`. Although this did solve the syntax error, the code does neither reach the statement `resolve('You need to select Ukraine :)')` or `swal('You selected: ' + country)`.

The Javascript code below is called in my html code like this:

```
<button onclick="testSweetalert()">test</button>
```

```js
async function testSweetalert() {

  const {value: country} = await swal({
       title: 'Select Ukraine',
       input: 'select',
       inputOptions: {
                'SRB': 'Serbia',
                'UKR': 'Ukraine',
                'HRV': 'Croatia'
       },
       inputPlaceholder: 'Select country',
       showCancelButton: true,
       inputValidator: (value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (value === 'UKR') {
            resolve()
          } else {
            resolve('You need to select Ukraine :)')
          }
        })
       }
    })
    if (country) {
            swal('You selected: ' + country)
    }
 }
```

Although I tried to learn more about `async` functions and using `Promise` I can't figure out what is wrong with the above code. This is specifically confusing me because the code examples I found on [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) work fine on their [github](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) page.

Comment: i found your question looking for a problem, copied your code and it worked perfectly. So, the code is fine, probably the problem was something else, like wrong library, or some previous error.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
(async () => {

const {value: country} = await swal.fire({
    title: 'Select Ukraine',
    input: 'select',
    inputOptions: {
        'SRB': 'Serbia',
        'UKR': 'Ukraine',
        'HRV': 'Croatia'
    },
    inputPlaceholder: 'Select country',
    showCancelButton: true,
    inputValidator: (value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (value === 'UKR') {
                resolve()
            } else {
                resolve('You need to select Ukraine :)')
            }
        })
    }
})
if (country) {
    swal.fire('You selected: ' + country)
}
})()
```

Reference: 
  [INPUT TYPE SELECT WITH SWEETALERT2](https://codepen.io/adrianotsi/pen/GRRGMOb)

Answer (score 0):

The error speaks for itself. You can use await only in async functions. Simply put the keyword "async" in front of the function. See below:

```
(async () => {
//your function
})()
```

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know now you need add

```
await swal.fire({
```